# Memory deallocation and exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I have a question regarding memory deallocation and exceptions. when I use delete to delete an object created on the heap . If an exception occurs before this delete is the memory going to leak or this delete is going to execute ?

Comment: You mean before, not during? Well then this is obvious that if the `delete` won't be called (because exception is thrown before) then no memory is freed. If you are asking of exception during destruction, then http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on where that `delete` is. If it's inside the `catch` that catches the exception, it might invoke.

```
try {
    f();  // throws
} catch( ... ) {
    delete p;  // will delete
}
```

If it's after the `catch` that catches the exception and that `catch` doesn't return from the function (i.e. allows execution flow to proceed after the `catch` block) then the `delete` might be called.

```
try {
    f();  // throws
} catch( ... ) {
    // execution proceeds beyond catch
}
delete p;  // will delete
```

If the `delete` is not in a `catch` block or after a `catch` block that allows execution to proceed then the `delete` will not call.

```
try {
    f();  // throws
    delete p;  // will not delete
}  // ...
```

As you may imagine, in the two first cases above the `delete` will not be invoked if there is a throw before the `delete`:

```
try {
    f();  // throws
} catch( ... ) {
    g();  // throws
    delete p;  // will not delete
}
```

Comment: Note that exceptions are good because you don't have to catch them in each function in the call stack. They can be cought on one "outer" level. How do you free the memory allocated within inner functions? Like for example if function f() that throws an exception allocated memory. Would it be a good idea to catch the exception within f() and free memory and then re-throw it to next level in call stack?

Answer (score 5):

In the case you describe, memory is going to leak.

Two tricks to avoid this problem :

- use smart pointers, which don't suffer from the same problem (preferred solution)
  --> the smart pointer in constructed on the stack, its destructor is therefore called, no matter what, and deletion of the pointed content is provided in the destructor
- use try/catch statements, and delete the item in catch statement as well

Answer (score 2):

It won't be called. Which is why you are encouraged to look at RAII. See [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#finally)

Answer (score 0):

We also have to make sure that "exception" really means C++ exception which can be caught by try/catch. There are other exceptions as well in the system which C++ try/catch cannot catch (e.g. division by 0).

In such cases(beyond the scope of C++ Standards), also, "delete" will not be executed unless these exceptions are caught and the handler explicitly invokes "delete" appropriately.